# I want to calculate the first and last indices of zeros which occur contiguously across a column of a matrix

Tags: matlab, indexing, zero

Say, I have the matrix x as

> > x=[1 5 0 6 0;2 6 0 3 0;0 0 5 5 0;0 0 0 8 9;0 0 0 0 8];

Hence

x =

```
 1     5     0     6     0
 2     6     0     3     0
 0     0     5     5     0
 0     0     0     8     9
 0     0     0     0     8
```

The result should be
1st col: (3,5)
2nd col: (3,5)
3rd col: (1,2) and (4,5)
4th col: (5,5)
5th col: (1,3)

OR

It will be better if I can get only the first and last indices of zeros across a column.
In this case the result should be
1st col: (3,5)
2nd col: (3,5)
3rd col: (1,5)
4th col: (5,5)
5th col: (1,3).

Comment: You haven't specified the language. `language-agnostic`-wise, it's trivial (assuming the matrix is indexable and iteration is allowed).

Comment: Thanks JD. It's MATLAB...

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is by combining `find` with `accumarray`:

```
[r,c]=find(x==0)
%# identify the first and the last zero for each column
firstIdx = accumarray(c,r,[size(x,2),1],@(x)min(x),NaN)
lastIdx  = accumarray(c,r,[size(x,2),1],@(x)max(x),NaN)
```